# Implement Image processing effects using WinRT api Windows 8 Metro apps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Need to implement Image processing effects like Blur, Black & White, Pinch Zoom in WinRT API. My approach has always been getting pixels from WritableBitmap Image object and apply changes on that. But as i can find in WinRT WritableBitmap don't provide any way to access individual level pixels. 
Other way suggested by people are to implement direct X and then apply using that. But for that I need to do coding using C++ about which i have zero experience.

Can anyone suggest some other way to do the same thing in C# WinRT api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Metro-Style-lightweight-24589f50
there is a sample code and article there.

Answer (score 3):

We searched the internet for programming toolkits that supports native WinRT. We found leadtools WinRT module that supports many features including image processing. For more information, see the following link:
http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/41843/ShowPost.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I worked on an app for WinRT that uses some image processing features such as converting images to black and white images, distortion, artistic effects..etc
I recall it used an sdk called leadtools and it helped me a lot in my implementation. Before I worked with this kit I tried the app they have on the App store to know how to use it. If you want search for it on the App store and see it has the desired effects you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try SharpDX (a managed wrapper for full DirectX).